# Cordova - getting 11353 error while mfpdev build adapter

Tags: maven, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I'm building my adapter using `mfpdev adapter build` and I'm getting something like this:

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXXX\adapters\exampleCode> mfpdev adapter build 
Building adapter...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for XX.XXX.XXX :exampleCode:adapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 103, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building exampleCode 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.007 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-14T11:15:16+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/182M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 11353
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error building adapter
undefined
Error: An error occurred during an attempt to build the adapter. See the preceding messages for details.
```

The `11353` is an error code or something else? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you see this problem with every adapter or just a specific adapter ( custom)?

Comment: I get this error with 5 on 10 adapters and funny thing is that, that my colleague build it on his iMac and didn't get this error, he got a build successful but we have same repo. (I'm working on Windows 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to delete all subfolders from:
`C:\Users\yourUserName\.m2\repository`

and then I didn't use:
`mfpdev adapter build`

but `mvn compile`.

Maven just download all necessary files, and then I just built it using MF command for building.